# Socket connection getting closed while reading data from socket

Tags: android, sockets

I am writting simple program to connect server by socket in android.
But when i try to read data from socket's outputstream it will send automatically RST request. so my connection gets closed. but i want my connection to open always.
Please any one help me.
Thank you.

```
try {
Socket socket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.x.xx", 9083);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
out.println("Testing");

InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        inputStream));
String readObject = reader.readLine();
System.out.println(readObject);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
     socket.getOutputStream())), true);
out.println(string);

Comment: You are sure it's not the server that closes the connection and you just receives the "connection closed" error?

Comment: I have checked in wireshark client only sending RST request after send the data.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what 'connection closed' error?

Comment: Getting "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer" from android mobile

Comment: I have tested above code that was working in emulator. but not working in android mobile. Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The most usual reason for 'connection reset' is that you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error.

Comment: same code is working on JavaProject. but it not working on android phone.

Comment: If this is the cause, the problem in your code would be that "you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end".